# glibc detected when trying to use cvCreateHist in C

Tags: c, image-processing, ubuntu, opencv, histogram

This is a part of my code

```
int histsize=16;
float range=[0,255];
float* ranges[] = { range };
bool uniform=true;
CvHistogram* hist = cvCreateHist(1, &histsize, CV_HIST_ARRAY, ranges, uniform);
```

But when I try to execute cvCreateHist the program terminates and throws an error saying
*** glibc detected**  malloc(): memory corruption: 0x083109b8 **

I am working in eclipse,Ubuntu.Please help me out.

Comment: That's C code, you should add the **C** tag.

Answer (score 0):

The truth is that **your code shouldn't even compile** because of these lines:

```
float range=[0,255];

bool uniform=true;1
```

Before answering this question, I must say that I think you can benefit a lot from this post: [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

I don't know what you are trying to do exactly with that code, but the following compiles & doesn't crash:

```
int histsize = 16;
float range[] = { 0, 255 };
float* ranges[] = { range };
bool uniform = true;
CvHistogram* hist = cvCreateHist(1, &histsize, CV_HIST_ARRAY, ranges, uniform);
```

Comment: Well the bool uniform=true;1 was a typo.I am sorry for that.But this code is in a function which I created and when I try to compile it,it fails

Comment: First you said your code crashed, now you are telling me it doesn't compile. What's really going on? Read and test the code on my answer before adding another comment.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion karl.the code does crash.I tried your code, as a standalone code it works,but what I am not able to understand is why does it throw a memory corrupted error when used in mine.

Comment: Probably due to `float range=[0,255];` , which makes GCC warn about `lambda expressions only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x` and scream a bunch of errors on my system.